# error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'pNamesPtr' used

Tags: c++

I'm working on a crypter project and  ran into the following error when attempting to compile the program.

> main.cpp(520): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer
>   variable 'pNamesPtr' used
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

```
        DLLNAMES[i].UsedAlready = 0;
    }


    *dwOutSize = (DWORD)pNamesPtr - (DWORD)pBuffer;//*<----is line 520 of error
    *dwImportsSize = *dwOutSize - *dwIATSize;    
    return pBuffer;
}
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
```

Can someone help me with this error? Do you need more code in order to have a good answer?

Comment: There's no way we can tell if you initialized it or not.

Comment: How you have declared `pNamesPtr`. Add the code for the same..

Answer (score 10):

This warning isn't always a bug.

For example if I write:

```
int i;

if (this_and_that)
    i = 5;

if (whatever)
    printf("%d\n", i);  // <--- this may give a potential blahblah warning
```

If you are optimizing then you may know that the value of `whatever` is always true when the value of `this_and_that` is true so if `printf` gets called then `i` is already guaranteed to be initialized but the compiler can not always figure out the relation between `this_and_that` and `whatever`, this is why you get the warning. One possible way to avoid a warning is initializing the variable to a default value right where you declare it. In my opinion sparing with initialization is bad practice and a source of bugs.

Comment: This happens to me a lot when I'm not careful - it's also true if you have an `if-else if-else` kind of setup, whereby you know the value of a variable/pointer will be set, since you have an `else`, but since they're all only sometimes called, the compiler will likely complain

Comment: @chrisb2244 yes, if we wanted to generalize my statement: This warning happens if you try to use a variable that isn't initialized on all possible code execution pathways between variable initialization and variable usage. So any control flow statement that generates code with "jump/goto" can cause this, for example `switch` could do the same but a more exotic control flow example: `break`-ing out from a loop may cause this if the initialzation of the variable is inside the loop after your break statement...

Comment: correcting my previous comment: between variable *declaration* and variable usage

Comment: else is equal to goto.

Answer (score 3):

It means that

- you don't initialise `pNamesPtr` when you declare it, so it starts with an invalid value; and
- the compiler can't be sure that you will have assigned a valid value to it before using it.

Check all the code paths from the declaration to the point of use. Do they all assign something sensible to the variable? If not, fix it so they do.

If they do, and you're convinced that you're assigning it correctly, could you simplify the code so that it's obvious to the compiler that it is?

If all else fails, then you could silence the compiler by initialising it to `nullptr` or some other default value in the initialisation. But only do that if you're really sure your code is correct - compilers are usually good at spotting mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

This error mean that compier don't know if used variable have assigned value.
For example:

```
int i;
if( someBool )
    i= 123;
someFunction();
if( someBool )
    printf("%d", i );
```

If `someFunction()` change value of `someBool` then you may end up calling `printf` with `i` argument while `i` doesn't have any value assigned.

If you are sure that your code is correct you may disbale that error in Visual Studio by putting at the top of your cpp file line:

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4703)
```

Or you may disable that check for whole project by going to `Properties` / `C/C++` /  `General` / `SDL checks` and set it to `No (/sdl-)`.

Alternatively if you don't care about performance you may just assign anything to `pNamesPtr` where it's defined.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your code:

```
xtype *pNamesPtr = NULL
```

Comment: I think this answer could be improved, it's not clear where it should be put and you're not highlighting the code with the proper formatting.